# what is the corresponding query in Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which works perfectly in postgresql:

```
Select 'Tom' as name
```

output as:

```
name
Tom
```

What should be the corresponding query in Oracle?

If I run the query in Oracle it gives an error, but is run successfully in postgresql.

Comment: You need to select from a table. Try `select 'Tom' as name from dual`.

Comment: @jarlh thanks it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow queries without a `from` clause. For these kind of queries, Oracle provides a system table called `dual`, with one column and one row:

```
SELECT 'Tom' as name FROM dual
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle needs the from clause. In that case, you have to use the DUAL table.

```
select 'Tom' as name from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is (afaik) unusual amongst other RMDBSs in that it enforces that if you're selecting something, you must select it from a table.

To that end, there is the [DUAL table](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036). It is a special, one row, one column table that allows you to select constants, functions etc within SQL, rather than having to write a PL/SQL procedure.

I say "special" because, since 10g, the optimizer recognises that it's different to other tables and can therefore make use of that information when generating the execution path to make it more efficient than if it was using a "normal" one column, one row table.

Comment: The Oracle behavior here is actually ANSI SQL compliant. According to the SQL standard a FROM clause is required.

Comment: @jarlh I'm not entirely sure about that; I think I read them at some point and they catered for the fact that when selecting a constant you didn't need the FROM clause. However, I can't find a copy of the standards online that I can use to confirm that as being true or not!

Comment: You can verify ISO/ANSI SQL syntax compliance here: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml

Comment: Oracle is not that "unusual".  DB2, Informix, SAP HANA, Firebird, HSQLDB, Apache Derby also require a `from` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name See, I knew someone else would know better! Maybe the ones that have optional from clauses are the unusual ones! *{;-)